# How to store additional data for users when signing up using firebase authentication?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In the `AuthService` of my Ionic / Angular app, I am signing up users & storing them in my firebase real-time database:

```
signUp(email: string, password: string) {
    return this.http.post<AuthResponseData>(
      `myFirebaseUrl/v1/accounts:signUp?key=${
      environment.firebaseAPIKey}
        `,
      { email: email, password: password, returnSecureToken: true }
    )
      .pipe(tap(this.setUserData.bind(this)));
  }
```

This is working as expected, as I can sign users up, & records are added to `Authentication` collection in firebase:

[image]

However, when users sign up, I want to store more information about them rather than just an email & password.

I've seen this is one way it can be done:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.then(
  (user)=>{
 // here you can use either the returned user object or       firebase.auth().currentUser. I will use the returned user object
    if(user){
      user.updateProfile({
         displayName: // some displayName,
         photoURL: // some photo url
      }).then(
        (s)=> // perform any other operation
      )
    }
})
});
```

But I haven't imported firebase. I also can't use `.then` in my current code.

Can someone please tell me what changes are required so I can save additional user info?

Comment: *"I was thinking of creating a new document in a Users collection for that User"* - yes, you could do that.  You'll have to consult the documentation for the database you've chosen in order to learn how to add data to it.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson Thanks for your comment. I've updated my question with some code. I can't use this code because I haven't imported firebase into my project, & I can't use a `.then()`. Would you know what changes I need to make so I can do something similar?